# Animation with multiple steps with smooth speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I want to make an animation in jQuery to move a div to another div smoothly but recalculating the coordinates of the final destination in case a user scrollsdown with his mouse for example.

The red square is absolute positioned and the blue square has a fixed position.

I had an idea of calling several times the stop() function and then animate again to the new position of the blue square but the transition isn't smooth at all.

Is there a way to set new destination from time to time but keeping it smooth?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gkLzh